# Usar Active Record con joins y ordenando por cantidad correctamente

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Estoy usando Rails 5 y estoy tratando de crear una query que me traiga a todos los usuarios ordenados por cantidad de libros leidos.

Cada usuario tiene muchos libros, algunos leidos y otros no.

`users :has_many books`

Tengo esta query que funciona bien excepto que me saca al usuario que no tiene ningun libro leido.

```
users = user
   .joins(:books)
   .where('books.read = ?', 1)
   .group('users.id')
   .order("count(books.user_id)")
```

Como puedo lograrlo con active record? o con SQL?

Update:

La columna `read` de `books` puede tener varios valores (1,2). Users pueden tener muchos o ningun libro.

Quiero los usuarios con y sin `books` ordenados por la cantidad de libros leidos, es decir, `books.read = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con [`left_joins`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_joins) como:

```
users = user
   .left_joins(:books)
   .where('books.read = ?', 1)
   .group('users.id')
   .order("count(books.user_id)")
```